# to select all the employees who have joined most recently under king

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

emp table

```
empno ename    sal    deptno mgr      job       comm  hiredate 

7369  SMITH   800.0000  20  7902      CLERK           1980-12-17 00:00:00.000
7499  ALLEN1  600.0000  30  7698      SALESMAN  300   1981-02-20 00:00:00.000
7521  WARD    1250.0000 30  7698      SALESMAN  500   1981-02-22 00:00:00.000
7566  JONES   2975.0000 20  7839      MANAGER         1981-04-02 00:00:00.000
7654  MARTIN  1250.0000 30  7839      SALESMAN  1400  1981-09-28 00:00:00.000
7698  BLAKE   2850.0000 30  7839      MANAGER         1981-05-01 00:00:00.000
7782  CLARK   2450.0000 10  7839      MANAGER         1981-06-09 00:00:00.000
7788  SCOTT   3000.0000 20  7566      ANALYST         1987-04-19 00:00:00.000
7839  KING    5000.0000 10            PRESIDENT       1981-11-17 00:00:00.000
7844  TURNER  1500.0000 30  7698      SALESMAN  0     1981-09-08 00:00:00.000
7876  ADAMS   1100.0000 20  7788      CLERK           1987-05-23 00:00:00.000
7900  JAMES   950.0000  30  7698      CLERK           1981-12-03 00:00:00.000
7902  FORD    3000.0000 20  7566      ANALYST         1981-12-03 00:00:00.000
7934  MILLER  1300.0000 10  7782      CLERK           1982-01-23 00:00:00.000
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
select e.*,datediff(dd,e.hiredate,getdate()) min_exp 
from emp e 
join emp e1 on e.mgr=e1.empno1 
where e1.empname='king' 
  and datediff(dd,e.hiredate,getdate()) = 
      (
          select min(datediff(dd,e.hiredate,getdate())) from emp
      )
```

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: select e.*,datediff(dd,e.hiredate,getdate()) min_exp from emp e join emp e1 on e.mgr=e1.empno1 where  e1.empname='king' 
and datediff(dd,e.hiredate,getdate()) = (select min(datediff(dd,e.hiredate,getdate()))from emp)

Comment: OK, so what are you trying to do here, and how does this query not achieve that?  (Your title doesn't really make sense, so you should explain it)

Answer (score 0):

So if you just need a list of employees that were hired after King was hired, just use King's hire date as the filter.

```
select e.*,datediff(dd,e.hiredate,getdate()) min_exp 
from emp e 
where e.hiredate > (SELECT hiredate FROM emp WHERE ename = 'king')
```

Test the statement and make adjustments where needed.  I didn't verify it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select top(1) from (
    select * from emp 
    where empname='king' order by hiredate desc
) t;
```